# Import Excel files in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel

I have a **Laravel 5.1** application and I want to import some Excel file to storage that data in my database.

I found one solution, the [Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel), but when I add `"maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"` to my **composer.json** and run a **composer update**, I get this error: https://pastebin.com/63LR0vSh

I have already tried to delete the vendor folder and run a **composer install**, run a **composer dump-autoload** but I still have no idea of how to fix that. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You should share your own code to help you. I recently used `mattwebsite/excel`. I tried to run with a fresh Laravel 5.1  and installed `mattwebsite/excel` with no problem.

Here my composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"
    },
```